# The very bottom of CellMargins is missing

Tags: front-end, bugs, notebooks, options, dialog-window

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persists through 12.0**

---

**Edit 16. IV 2016** I've received an answer from WRI Support:

> [...] It does appear that `CellMargins` is not interacting correctly with `WindowSize->All`, and I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. I have also included your contact information so that you can be notified once this gets resolved. [...]

Which I believe confirms that this is a bug. I'd appreciate checking that in earlier versions of MMA.

---

`DialogInput` has by default those annoying margins settings (missing a bottom one):

```
DialogInput[Pane@RandomImage[]]
```

> [image]

What is the best/shortest way to make them even.

Let's not touch stylesheets here.

It seems that the problem is more general. I was suspecting that somwhere deep in definitions of `DialogInput` some options are prepended but here I'm just using basic code to generate the issue:

```
NotebookPut @ Notebook[
  List @ Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Pane[
    RandomImage[], ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0
  ],
  WindowSize -> All, 
  WindowElements -> None, 
  "CellInsertionPointCell" -> None, 
  WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox"},
  ShowCellBracket -> False, 
  CellMargins -> 10
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a straightforward way to set `CellMargins` to be zero:

```
DialogInput[
 DialogNotebook[{ExpressionCell[Pane[RandomImage[], ImageMargins -> 8], 
    CellMargins -> 0]}]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Instead of `ImageMargins` we can rely on `CellFrameMargins`:

```
DialogInput[
 DialogNotebook[{ExpressionCell[RandomImage[], CellMargins -> 0, CellFrameMargins -> 8, 
    CellFrame -> True, CellFrameColor -> None]}]]
```

[image: screenshot]

On my system (Windows 7 x64) with *Mathematica* 10.4 the `CellFrameMargins` method gives more accurate results than `ImageMargins` (compare the screenshots):

```
DialogInput[
 DialogNotebook[{ExpressionCell[Pane[RandomImage[], ImageMargins -> 1], 
    CellMargins -> 0]}]]

DialogInput[
 DialogNotebook[{ExpressionCell[RandomImage[], CellMargins -> 0, CellFrameMargins -> 1, 
    CellFrame -> True, CellFrameColor -> None]}]]
```

[image: screenshot with ImageMargins -> 1] 
[image: screenshot with CellFrameMargins -> 1]

---

From your second example in the question I believe that this behavior is determined by the `WindowSize -> All` Notebook option which makes the window

> large enough to fit all **visible** contents

(emphasis mine).

It seems that FrontEnd crops `CellMargins` because they "aren't visible". But with this explanation the inconsistency is that it crops them only at the bottom but not on the right even if we switch off displaying of the cell bracket:

```
NotebookPut@
 Notebook[{Cell@
    BoxData@ToBoxes@Pane[RandomImage[], ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0]}, 
  WindowSize -> All, WindowElements -> None, ShowCellBracket -> False, 
  WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox"}, CellMargins -> 10]
```

[image: screenshot]

If we add another cell we can see that `CellMargins` are actually respected:

```
NotebookPut@
 Notebook[Table[
   Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes@Pane[RandomImage[], ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], {2}], 
  WindowSize -> All, WindowElements -> None, ShowCellBracket -> False, 
  WindowFrameElements -> {"CloseBox"}, CellMargins -> 10]
```

[image: screenshot]

So I'm inclined to think that we have a bug in handling of the `WindowSize -> All` option: the expected behavior for this option is to treat `CellMargins` as *visible* contents and make the window to be sufficiently large to include the whole `CellMargins`.

Comment: Yep, that's shorter than mine. I believe I've used something like that once but I forgot due to the confusion about all those DialogNotebook/CreateWindow/Notebook and friends. Do you possibly have any idea what's the root of the problem?

Comment: @Kuba I think it's a bug. I have read the Dialog.nb stylesheet but haven't found anything what could explain this. I also wasn't able to reproduce this with the default stylesheet (but I haven't spend much time on this).

Comment: The second example in the question includes the default.nb stylesheet. I just had to get rid of some elements to make this effect visible. I've sent a support question, CASE:3579534 created, will keep you informed.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, I overlooked the second example. I have updated the answer with new findings.

Comment: @Kuba Added `CellFrameMargins`-based workaround and the comparison.

Answer (score 6):

I gave up looking for neat solution. Here's brute force.

Since the bottom CellMargins are not respected then let's not use any! :) We can use `Pane` and its `ImageMargins` to take control over padding.

```
DialogInput[
   DynamicModule[{},
      Pane[RandomImage[], ImageMargins -> 8],
      Initialization :> (SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellMargins -> 0])
   ]
]
```

[image]

So in general instead of `RandomImage[]` put the code you would have used in `DialogInput`.

Comment: I love brute force solutions :)

Answer (score 3):

It really expects that you have some buttons along the bottom.

```
DialogInput[Column[{Pane @ RandomImage[], Button["OK", DialogReturn[0]]}]]
```

[image: dialog1]

but you can do it this way

```
DialogInput[Column[{Pane @ RandomImage[], ""}]]
```

[image: dialog2]

#### Update

I Think it looks better with the bottom margin a bit larger than the top, but if you are being picky about equal margins, try

```
DialogInput[Column[{Pane@RandomImage[], ""}, Spacings -> 0]]
```

[image: dialog3]

Comment: But I don't have any Buttons. Both you examples have the bottom margin different than the rest of them.

Comment: @Kuba. see update

Comment: Yes, that's good quick fix thanks. Unfortunately it doesn't give a precision/control, over those margins, that I'm after.