# Definition of the vertical size of the enclosing region in CreateDialog and DialogNotebook

Tags: programming, gui-construction

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any options that would allow me to control the vertical size of the enclosing region in `CreateDialog` and `DialogNotebook`.  It seems that the size is not related to the value that is set in `WindowSize` for either of the options.

For example,

```
CreateDialog[
  {
   Grid[{{""}}, Frame -> True, ItemSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}]
   },
  WindowSize -> {200, 100}
  ];
```

creates a dialog of the correct size. However, the vertical size of the enclosing region does not seem to be consistent with the size of the window:

[image]

The behaviour persists if `DialogNotebook` and `CreateWindow` are used instead of `CreateDialog`:

```
CreateWindow[
  DialogNotebook[{
    Grid[
     {{}},
     ItemSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]},
     Frame -> True
     ]
    },
   WindowSize -> {200, 100}
   ],
  WindowSize -> {200, 100},
  WindowMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
  ScrollingOptions -> {"VerticalScrollRange" -> Automatic}
  ];
```

Note: I am using Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.5 and Mathematica 11.1.1.0.

---

EDIT

Following a comment that was made by @Kuba, I thought that a potential worakaround could be to provide an embedding element with the fixed image size to `Grid`:

```
CreateDialog[
 Pane[
  Grid[
   {{"qqq"}},
   ItemSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[0.8]},
   Frame -> True,
   Alignment -> Top
   ],
  ImageMargins -> 0,
  ImageSize -> {200, 100}
  ],
 WindowSize -> {220, 120}
 ]
```

However, unfortunately, the result was identical. The result was also similar when I tried to use `Framed` instead of `Pane`.

Comment: Using `Scaled` is always a pain because they do not respect different types of margins/frames in ways one would expect. So it works correctly, it just ignores cell margins. I'd go with something like: `CreateDialog[Framed[  {""}
  , ImageSize -> {200, 100}  ] , WindowSize -> All]`. Keep in mind that [The very bottom of CellMargins is missing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112593/5478).

Comment: Do you need to use ItemSize? My point was to skip it, in Grid it works with line/characters units so it is tough to manage. Also the parent container is a cell so it will be tough to use scaled height of it, unless we force it like I've demonstrated.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for your comments. I decided to follow your advice and not use `ItemSize`. However, my question does come down to the ability to control the size of the enclosing object of the `Grid` that is embedded in `CreateDialog`. The horizontal size of the enclosing object seems to be governed through the `WindowSize` of `CreateDialog`. However, I could not find a way to control the vertical size of the enclosing object. Also, sorry for deleting the question with your comment - I decided that it was, effectively, duplicate/specialisation of the question in the link that you have posted.

Comment: If you want to control vertical size you need to use a wrapper like my `Framed`, it is because Cell's height is automatically adjusted to fit contents, so the full height will be of height of the notebook, but then cell margins are ignored and you have misaligned content.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for your comment. The problem is that `Grid` does not seem to recognise `Framed` or `Pane` as its enclosing object, even if the `Grid` is located inside `Framed` or `Pane`. Please see the EDIT part in the formulation of the question. I used `Pane` as an example, but the effect is similar when `Framed` is used (the result is not entirely identical for `Framed`, but the vertical size of the `Grid` does not seem to be identical to the vertical size of the enclosing `Framed` when `Scaled` is set to `1`.